# Hide/Show rows based on multiple dropdown selections (filtering)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, selection

So my question is this. I have a table and I am hiding/showing rows based on a dropdown menu selection. What would like to have is the 2 menus working together rather than independently. If I select an item in the first dropdown, I would like to be able then to filter that item further with the second dropdown and so on with any additional dropdown. Here's the code I'm using that works independently currently.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select#age').bind('change',function(){
  if($(this).val()=='Show All'){
   $('td.age').parent().show();
  }else{
   $('td.age').parent().hide();
   $('td.age:contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').parent().show();
  }
  $('#counts').html( $('table.data_table tr:visible').length-1 + ' Registered Kids' )    
 })
  $('select#sport').bind('change',function(){
  if($(this).val()=='Show All'){
   $('td.sport').parent().show();
  }else{
   $('td.sport').parent().hide();
   $('td.sport:contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').parent().show();
  }
  $('#counts').html( $('table.data_table tr:visible').length-1 + ' Registered Kids' )    
 })
})
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the table of data snippet too...

Comment: Are you looking for like an actual snippet of data from the table or the code generating the table itself. Sorry, I'm like falling asleep at the keyboard here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ddlFilterTableRow = $('select.ddlFilterTableRow'),
        headerCount = $('#headerCount');
          headerCount.html($('#tableRegisterKids').find('.Row').length + ' Registered Kids');

    ddlFilterTableRow.on('change', function() {
        ddlFilterTableRow.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        var records = $('#tableRegisterKids').find('.Row');
        records.hide();

        var critriaAttributes = [];
        ddlFilterTableRow.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $selectedLength = $this.find(':selected').length,
                $critriaAttribute = '';

            if ($selectedLength > 0 && $this.val() != '0') {
                if ($selectedLength == 1) {
                    $critriaAttribute += '[data-' + $this.data('attribute') + '*="' + $this.val() + '"]';
                } else {
                    var $startDataAttribute = '[data-' + $this.data('attribute') + '*="',
                        $endDataAttribute = '"]',
                        $selectedValues = $this.val().toString();

                    $critriaAttribute += $startDataAttribute + $selectedValues.replaceAll(',', ($endDataAttribute + ',' + $startDataAttribute)) + $endDataAttribute;
                }
                critriaAttributes.push($critriaAttribute);
            }
        });

        var $showRecords = records;
        if (critriaAttributes.length > 0) {
            $.each(critriaAttributes, function(i, filterValue) {
                $showRecords = $showRecords.filter(filterValue);
            });
        }
        $showRecords.show();

        headerCount.html($showRecords.length + ' Registered Kids');

        ddlFilterTableRow.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

//================================================================//

```
<select id="ddlAge" class="ddlFilterTableRow" data-attribute="age">
    <option value="0">Select All</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlSport" class="ddlFilterTableRow" data-attribute="sports">
    <option value="0">Select All</option>
    <option value="Foot Ball">Foot Ball</option>
    <option value="Chess">Chess</option>
    <option value="Cricket">Cricket</option>
</select>
<h1 id="headerCount"></h1>
<table id="tableRegisterKids">
    <tr>
        <th>Fullname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="10" data-sports="Foot Ball">
        <td>Thulasiram.S</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Foot Ball</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="8" data-sports="Cricket">
        <td>ST Ram</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Cricket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="6" data-sports="Chess">
        <td>Ram Kumar.S</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Chess</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="8" data-sports="Chess">
        <td>Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Chess</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="6" data-sports="Foot Ball">
        <td>Raja Ram.S</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Foot Ball</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="10" data-sports="Chess">
        <td>Priya</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Chess</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please find for [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YRea3/157/)

Comment: you need like this output?

Comment: How would I update this to filter on a comma separated list in the data attribute? If the data-sports="Chess, Cricket" and from the dropdown I select "Cricket" or "Chess" I want this to be part of the result.

Comment: @TheEUG: Please replace with below code critriaAttribute += '[data-' + $(this).data('attribute') + '*="' + $(this).val() + '"]';

Comment: @TheEUG: You are Welcome... :-)

Comment: @Thulasiram how would I make this work with a select where the user can select multiple options?

Comment: @TheEUG: If user select A, B option for drop down, we need to display (A && B) or (A || B) matched row?

Comment: @Thulasiram if the user selects A, B options in the drop down, we need to display items with (A || B). So if the user selects "Football" and "Chess" in the drop down, we should display matched with (Football ANDOR Chess)

Comment: @TheEUG: Please find the updated answer with Demo link.

Comment: @TheEUG: This script will work for single & multiple selection in drop down. For multiple selection in drop down, please add two additional attribute, multiple="multiple" size="3" Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YRea3/158/