# Hide/Show rows based on multiple selections in dropdown using checkbox (filtering)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filtering

my problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209680/hide-show-rows-based-on-multiple-dropdown-selections-filtering) question but i am trying multiple selection option in dropdown menu using checkbox.i.e. I can only select one item at a time for filtering instead of this i want multiple selection for filtering.Thank you.

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Then the solution must be similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14210991)

Comment: @Satpal no there is only one selection in dropdown menu i am trying multiple selection in dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQuery MultiSelect](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) its a dropdown with multi-select. see this [demo](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/).

Comment: @Evya2005How do i use this with table database for filtering?

Comment: To retrieve all selected values u can use:
var values = $("select").val();

OR:
var array_of_checked_values = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
   return this.value;    
}).get();